# How to integrate AWS WAF Captcha in vuejs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, captcha, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

I'm trying to integrate aws captcha to my login screen.

the captcha renders, user completes puzzle and verify api is called successfully.

but how do I get the success status after puzzle completed

```
AwsWafCaptcha.renderCaptcha(container, {
      apiKey: "ApiKeyHere",
      onSuccess: captchaExampleSuccessFunction,
      onError: captchaExampleErrorFunction
    });



captchaExampleSuccessFunction(wafToken) {
        window.AwsWafIntegration.fetch(this.captchaVerifiedFn());
    },
```

I need to call captchaVerifiedFn() after user completes puzzle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`captchaExampleSuccessFunction(wafToken)` is the success indicator. After you Render the captcha and the user completes it successfully `captchaExampleSuccessFunction(wafToken)` gets called which includes a token. It would not get called if the capture failed. If you want to do things between the successful captcha completion and you submitting data to your backend you can use `AwsWafIntegration` which has methods to check the token such as `checkForceRefresh`, `fetch`, `forceRefreshToken`, `getToken`, `hasToken`

Also reading your last line you say "I need to call captchaVerifiedFn() after user completes puzzle." cant you just move the `captchaVerifiedFn` outside of the fetch `captchaExampleSuccessFunction(wafToken) { this.captchaVerifiedFn(); },`

Comment: Tried this ```captchaExampleSuccessFunction(wafToken) { this.captchaVerifiedFn(); }, ``` doing this will execute this line even without completing the puzzle. (I mean this.captchaVerifiedFn() will be called right after rendering the puzzle)

Comment: something is wrong with your setup if that line gets called after just the render of the puzzle, captchaExampleSuccessFunction should only be called on a successful completion of the captcha challenge.